# PySpark Cannot Read JSON File

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I am trying to read a json file using pyspark and I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def spark_s():
   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local").getOrCreate()
   return spark

def get_data(spark_s):
   spark = spark_s
   data = spark.read.json('C:/projects/ml_project/heart.json')
   return data
```

The path is correct, it just keeps outputting the same error when I try to run it.

Comment: You are assigning a function when doing `spark = spark_s`. Try with `spark = spark_s()` instead

Comment: @blackbishop Thank you, I cannot believe I missed that.